# video clips keep disapearing

Tags: image, video-sequence-editor, video, error, audio

[image]

this is the first video I'm editing on blender and when i was in the middle of editing videos i looked back and saw all my past clips greyed out and not showing anything on the preview or playing any sound. the non greyed out ones still work fine. I've tried undoing, restarting the app and my computer but it still stays the same. this has happened twice with this one project and i cant find anyone else having this problem. is all my work gone and if so how do i stop this from happening again?

Comment: holy crap thank you !!!! im so glad it was that easy <3

Answer (score 0):

A comment that turned out to be the answer:
The clips look hidden. Press A to select them all, then press Alt + H to unhide them.